# Как реализовать Api

Tags: c++

мне бы хотелось узнать как я могу реализовать API для написания скриптов, у меня есть не маленький проект написанный на c++ который компилируется в DLL, эту длл загружает программа, я бы хотел писать скрипты на c#, апи для переноса в проект c# готова, но как мне перенести Api ? Dll используется клиентом игры, мой план состоит в том что бы писать необходимые скрипты для игры на языке c#, дальше этот скрипт должен подгружаться в игру что бы он работал.

Comment: Как я понял, вы хотите функции этой DLL вызывать из C#? Есть два способа: использовать `DllImport` или написать оболочку (wrapper) на C++/CLI.

Comment: Есть ещё вариант использовать COM, но наверняка это будет сложнее сделать.

Comment: Я думаю метод с C++ cli мне больше подходит, но у меня возникла проблема, как я могу подключить мою DLL к проекту C++ CLI ? Сама Dll загружается приложением, и соответственно данные в нем меняются, и эти данные необходимы для корректной работы API

Comment: Опишите подробнее, кто кого вызывает, что на чём написано (на каком языке) и куда вы хотите вставить скрипты. Не пишите это в комментариях, отредактируйте вопрос.